# Unable to connect db2 database in JMeter

Tags: jdbc, jmeter, db2

Getting below response on connecting to DB2 database:

---

> *"Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory ([jcc][t4][10109][10354][3.59.81] The version of the IBM Universal JDBC driver in use is not licensed for connectivity to QDB2 databases. To connect to this server, please obtain a licensed copy of the IBM DB2 Universal Driver for JDBC and SQLJ.
>   An appropriate license file db2jcc_license_*.jar for this target platform must be installed to the application class path. Connectivity to QDB2 databases is enabled by any of the following license files: [ db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar ]. ERRORCODE=-4472, SQLSTATE=42968)"*

---

db2jcc.jar and db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar already added in JMeter(3.2)'s lib folder.

My configuration:

[image: configuration]

Screenshot of the jmeter/lib folder:

[image]

Comment: The directory containing db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar  has to be on the CLASSPATH.   Verifyt that is the case at your site.  Additionally you are using an old (unsupported) version of the jdbc driver - your version corresponds to Db2-connect v9.5 fixpack 6a, so you should upgrade your jdbc driver to a currently supported version (such as the one supplied with Db2 v11) downloadable from IBM fix central. The version of the dbcjcc_license_cisuz.jar has to match the version of the Db2 *server*

Comment: "The directory containing db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar has to be on the CLASSPATH"--- Whether this line means putting db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar in JMeter(3.2)'s lib folder.Additionally I added both jars location in Environment Variable's >> Variable Name= CLASSPATH and Variable Value=C:\Users\SG45565\Downloads\apache-jmeter-3.2\lib\db2jcc_license_cu.jar;C:\Users\SG45565\Downloads\apache-jmeter-3.2\lib\db2jcc.jar.Are you asking for updated db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar.Can u give it's download path.I can't modify my jdbc driver since it's my organization's environment.Can u please suggest something else?

Comment: Your CLASSPATH value shows db2jcc_license_cu.jar ,but it needs to show instead db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar   , in addition to the db2jcc.jar.

Answer (score 0):

Although the message seems to indicate a license issue , I see an error in your configuration on Validation Query.

Can you try to fix it and see if you still get the error ?

Change it to:

> select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1

Also can you show a screenshot of the jmeter/lib folder and highlight the presence of the 2 jars for DB2 ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17721867)

Comment: It is not a critique, there is really an issue due to Validation Query.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is about mismatch of the [DB2 JDBC Driver](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363866) you are trying to use with JMeter and DB2 version on the server.

See [IBM data server client and driver types](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.install.doc/doc/c0022612.html) IBM KB article for more information on JDBC driver types.

Personally I would recommend obtaining JDBC driver **directly from your DB2 installation**, it normally lives under `java` or `jdbc` folder in the DB2 server installation root.

[image: JMeter DB2]

So I would recommend copying the following files somewhere to [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) (normally "lib" folder of your JMeter installation)

- db2jcc4.jar
- db2jcc_license_cu.jar

(depending on your DB2 version and type you might need other files as well)

JMeter restart will be required to pick the .jars up.

See [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter) article to learn more about databases load testing concept using JMeter.